# Is there a way to find response times of search results in Load Testing?

Tags: performance, testing, load, loadrunner

I am trying to do some performance testing for our application. 
My task is to do some load testing for a search page. Have to get the response times of the search results. ex: I searched with firstname and lastname and I get results in the grid. I have to get the response time, in how many seconds did i get the results ?

Can some please direct me on how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Place a set of transaction markers around your submission of search terms and the response associated with them.  This concept and implementation is covered in the self-paced training, the traditional instructor lead training material, the online documentation installed with LoadRunner as well as within many examples of the help files.

It is worthwhile to ask, has your management allowed you the time to go to training and provided you with a mentor for your first 4-12 months of work in this space?  if not, then they are likely more interested in billing for a capability rather than delivering value on a capability.

In the alternative, you may also turn on the w3c time-taken field in your HTTP logs.   This will collect to the millisecond of precision (in the logs) the time required to service this request.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple concept described how to get response times in LR. In fact, you could find more useful example from the Help on LoadRunner.

In this example, you could add transaction **lr_start_transaction("001_SearchResult");** before your search script.

When LR get expected text **"firstname and lastname"** from the resul on your browser, transaction pass, and LR will calculate the response time. IF LR does not get expeted text, transaction fail.

[image]